# What are the CPLEX option default values

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo, opl

I have a MIP Non-linear problem modeled twice

1. first with python, pyomo, cplex as the solver.
2. second in native OPL cplex.

although the model is typically the same (objective, constraints, variables) they are all the same but the objective is different, and the time to solve in python is faster!

I want to know the default values for the solver in both environments. My expectation, if the solver configurations are the same the solution also should be.

Please correct my understanding if I'm missing something.

Comment: MIP solve results may change according to CPLEX versions and machine (OS,  CPU,...), so the first thing is to make sur you compare runs on the same machine with same version.  You can also print the solve logs in both cases and compare: the log contains cplex versions, parameter values, etc.

Comment: Your model may have some variability . You could check that with https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/22.1.1?topic=cplex-evaluating-variability

Answer (score 0):

With OPL scripting you can get all default options.

In your CPLEX files, you can see in the folder CPLEX_Studio2211\cplex\include\ilcplex the file cpxconst.h where you will see

```
#define CPXPARAM_Advance 1001
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Algorithm 3007
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_ColNonzeros 3009
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_ConvergeTol 3002
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Crossover 3018
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Display 3010
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Corrections 3013
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Growth 3003
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Iteration 3012
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_ObjRange 3004
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Ordering 3014
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_QCPConvergeTol 3020
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_StartAlg 3017
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Strategy 1501
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Tolerances_FeasibilityCut 1509
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Tolerances_OptimalityCut 1510
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_WorkerAlgorithm 1500
#define CPXPARAM_ClockType 1006
#define CPXPARAM_Conflict_Algorithm 1073
#define CPXPARAM_Conflict_Display 1074
#define CPXPARAM_CPUmask 1144
#define CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit 1127
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_Memory 1082
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_MIP 2058
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_Numerical 1083
#define CPXPARAM_Feasopt_Mode 1084
#define CPXPARAM_Feasopt_Tolerance 2073
#define CPXPARAM_LPMethod 1062
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_BQP 2195
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Cliques 2003
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Covers 2005
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Disjunctive 2053
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_FlowCovers 2040
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Gomory 2049
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_GUBCovers 2044
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Implied 2041
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_LiftProj 2152
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_LocalImplied 2181
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_MCFCut 2134
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_MIRCut 2052
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Nodecuts 2157
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_PathCut 2051
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_RLT 2196
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_ZeroHalfCut 2111
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Display 2012
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Interval 2013
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_AggForCut 2054
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_AuxRootThreads 2139
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_CutPasses 2056
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_CutsFactor 2033
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_EachCutLimit 2102
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_GomoryCand 2048
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_GomoryPass 2050
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_LowerObjStop 2233
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Nodes 2017
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Populate 2108
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_ProbeDetTime 2150
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_ProbeTime 2065
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_RepairTries 2067
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Solutions 2015
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_StrongCand 2045
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_StrongIt 2046
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_TreeMemory 2027
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_UpperObjStop 2234
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_OrderType 2032
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_AbsMIPGap 2126
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_DetTime 2151
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_MIPGap 2127
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Nodes 2128
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Solutions 2129
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Time 2130
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_AbsGap 2106
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Capacity 2103
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Intensity 2107
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_RelGap 2105
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Replace 2104
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Backtrack 2002
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_BBInterval 2039
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Branch 2001
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_CardLs 2235
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Dive 2060
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_File 2016
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_FPHeur 2098
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_HeuristicEffort 2120
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_HeuristicFreq 2031
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_KappaStats 2137
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_LBHeur 2063
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_MIQCPStrat 2110
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_NodeSelect 2018
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Order 2020
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_PresolveNode 2037
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Probe 2042
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_RINSHeur 2061
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Search 2109
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_StartAlgorithm 2025
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_SubAlgorithm 2026
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_VariableSelect 2028
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_StartAlg 2205
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_SubAlg 2206
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_NodeLimit 2212
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_Scale 2207
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_AbsMIPGap 2008
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_Linearization 2068
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_Integrality 2010
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_LowerCutoff 2006
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap 2009
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_ObjDifference 2019
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_RelObjDifference 2022
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_UpperCutoff 2007
#define CPXPARAM_MultiObjective_Display 1600
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Display 5005
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Iterations 5001
#define CPXPARAM_Network_NetFind 1022
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Pricing 5004
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Tolerances_Feasibility 5003
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Tolerances_Optimality 5002
#define CPXPARAM_OptimalityTarget 1131
#define CPXPARAM_Output_CloneLog 1132
#define CPXPARAM_Output_IntSolFilePrefix 2143
#define CPXPARAM_Output_MPSLong 1081
#define CPXPARAM_Output_WriteLevel 1114
#define CPXPARAM_Parallel 1109
#define CPXPARAM_ParamDisplay 1163
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Aggregator 1003
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_BoundStrength 2029
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_CoeffReduce 2004
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Dependency 1008
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Dual 1044
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Fill 1002
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Folding 1164
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_NumPass 1052
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Presolve 1030
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QCPDuals 4003
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QPMakePSD 4010
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QToLin 4012
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Reduce 1057
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Reformulations 1167
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Relax 2034
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_RepeatPresolve 2064
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_SOS1Reform 2230
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_SOS2Reform 2231
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Symmetry 2059
#define CPXPARAM_QPMethod 1063
#define CPXPARAM_RandomSeed 1124
#define CPXPARAM_Read_APIEncoding 1130
#define CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck 1056
#define CPXPARAM_Read_FileEncoding 1129
#define CPXPARAM_Read_Scale 1034
#define CPXPARAM_Read_WarningLimit 1157
#define CPXPARAM_Record 1162
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Algorithm 1077
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Simplex 1158
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Display 1076
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Iterations 1078
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Crash 1007
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_DGradient 1009
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Display 1019
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_DynamicRows 1161
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Iterations 1020
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_LowerObj 1025
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Perturbation 1028
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Singularity 1037
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_UpperObj 1026
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Perturbation_Constant 1015
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Perturbation_Indicator 1027
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_PGradient 1029
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Pricing 1010
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Refactor 1031
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Feasibility 1016
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Markowitz 1013
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Optimality 1014
#define CPXPARAM_SolutionType 1147
#define CPXPARAM_Threads 1067
#define CPXPARAM_TimeLimit 1039
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_DetTimeLimit 1139
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Display 1113
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Measure 1110
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Repeat 1111
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_TimeLimit 1112
#define CPXPARAM_WorkDir 1064
#define CPXPARAM_WorkMem 1065
```

that you can save in listcplexparam.txt

And then in OPL you can run

```
{int} params={};

execute
{
  var f=new IloOplInputFile("listcplexparam.txt");
  while (!f.eof)
  {
    var line=f.readline();
    var param=Opl.atoi(line.substring(line.length-4,line.length));
    writeln(line);
    writeln(param," ==> ",cplex.params[param]);
  }
  f.close();
}
```

that will read that file and get you all the default settings

```
#define CPXPARAM_Advance 1001
1001 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Algorithm 3007
3007 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_ColNonzeros 3009
3009 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_ConvergeTol 3002
3002 ==> 1.000000000e-08
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Crossover 3018
3018 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Display 3010
3010 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Corrections 3013
3013 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Growth 3003
3003 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_Iteration 3012
3012 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Limits_ObjRange 3004
3004 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_Ordering 3014
3014 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_QCPConvergeTol 3020
3020 ==> 1.000000000e-07
#define CPXPARAM_Barrier_StartAlg 3017
3017 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Strategy 1501
1501 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Tolerances_FeasibilityCut 1509
1509 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_Tolerances_OptimalityCut 1510
1510 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_Benders_WorkerAlgorithm 1500
1500 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_ClockType 1006
1006 ==> 2
#define CPXPARAM_Conflict_Algorithm 1073
1073 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Conflict_Display 1074
1074 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_CPUmask 1144
1144 ==> auto
#define CPXPARAM_DetTimeLimit 1127
1127 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_Memory 1082
1082 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_MIP 2058
2058 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Emphasis_Numerical 1083
1083 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Feasopt_Mode 1084
1084 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Feasopt_Tolerance 2073
2073 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_LPMethod 1062
1062 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_BQP 2195
2195 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Cliques 2003
2003 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Covers 2005
2005 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Disjunctive 2053
2053 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_FlowCovers 2040
2040 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Gomory 2049
2049 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_GUBCovers 2044
2044 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Implied 2041
2041 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_LiftProj 2152
2152 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_LocalImplied 2181
2181 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_MCFCut 2134
2134 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_MIRCut 2052
2052 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_Nodecuts 2157
2157 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_PathCut 2051
2051 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_RLT 2196
2196 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Cuts_ZeroHalfCut 2111
2111 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Display 2012
2012 ==> 2
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Interval 2013
2013 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_AggForCut 2054
2054 ==> 3
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_AuxRootThreads 2139
2139 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_CutPasses 2056
2056 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_CutsFactor 2033
2033 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_EachCutLimit 2102
2102 ==> 2100000000
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_GomoryCand 2048
2048 ==> 200
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_GomoryPass 2050
2050 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_LowerObjStop 2233
2233 ==> -2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Nodes 2017
2017 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Populate 2108
2108 ==> 20
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_ProbeDetTime 2150
2150 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_ProbeTime 2065
2065 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_RepairTries 2067
2067 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_Solutions 2015
2015 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_StrongCand 2045
2045 ==> 10
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_StrongIt 2046
2046 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_TreeMemory 2027
2027 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_UpperObjStop 2234
2234 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_OrderType 2032
2032 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_AbsMIPGap 2126
2126 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_DetTime 2151
2151 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_MIPGap 2127
2127 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Nodes 2128
2128 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Solutions 2129
2129 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_PolishAfter_Time 2130
2130 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_AbsGap 2106
2106 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Capacity 2103
2103 ==> 2100000000
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Intensity 2107
2107 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_RelGap 2105
2105 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Pool_Replace 2104
2104 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Backtrack 2002
2002 ==> 0.9999
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_BBInterval 2039
2039 ==> 7
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Branch 2001
2001 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_CardLs 2235
2235 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Dive 2060
2060 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_File 2016
2016 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_FPHeur 2098
2098 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_HeuristicEffort 2120
2120 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_HeuristicFreq 2031
2031 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_KappaStats 2137
2137 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_LBHeur 2063
2063 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_MIQCPStrat 2110
2110 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_NodeSelect 2018
2018 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Order 2020
2020 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_PresolveNode 2037
2037 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Probe 2042
2042 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_RINSHeur 2061
2061 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_Search 2109
2109 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_StartAlgorithm 2025
2025 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_SubAlgorithm 2026
2026 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Strategy_VariableSelect 2028
2028 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_StartAlg 2205
2205 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_SubAlg 2206
2206 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_NodeLimit 2212
2212 ==> 500
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_SubMIP_Scale 2207
2207 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_AbsMIPGap 2008
2008 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_Linearization 2068
2068 ==> 0.001
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_Integrality 2010
2010 ==> 0.00001
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_LowerCutoff 2006
2006 ==> -2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap 2009
2009 ==> 0.0001
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_ObjDifference 2019
2019 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_RelObjDifference 2022
2022 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_UpperCutoff 2007
2007 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_MultiObjective_Display 1600
1600 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Display 5005
5005 ==> 2
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Iterations 5001
5001 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Network_NetFind 1022
1022 ==> 2
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Pricing 5004
5004 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Tolerances_Feasibility 5003
5003 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_Network_Tolerances_Optimality 5002
5002 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_OptimalityTarget 1131
1131 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Output_CloneLog 1132
1132 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Output_IntSolFilePrefix 2143
2143 ==> 
#define CPXPARAM_Output_MPSLong 1081
1081 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Output_WriteLevel 1114
1114 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Parallel 1109
1109 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_ParamDisplay 1163
1163 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Aggregator 1003
1003 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_BoundStrength 2029
2029 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_CoeffReduce 2004
2004 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Dependency 1008
1008 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Dual 1044
1044 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Fill 1002
1002 ==> 10
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Folding 1164
1164 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_NumPass 1052
1052 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Presolve 1030
1030 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QCPDuals 4003
4003 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QPMakePSD 4010
4010 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_QToLin 4012
4012 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Reduce 1057
1057 ==> 3
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Reformulations 1167
1167 ==> 3
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Relax 2034
2034 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_RepeatPresolve 2064
2064 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_SOS1Reform 2230
2230 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_SOS2Reform 2231
2231 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Preprocessing_Symmetry 2059
2059 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_QPMethod 1063
1063 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_RandomSeed 1124
1124 ==> 202009243
#define CPXPARAM_Read_APIEncoding 1130
1130 ==> ISO-8859-1
#define CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck 1056
1056 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Read_FileEncoding 1129
1129 ==> ISO-8859-1
#define CPXPARAM_Read_Scale 1034
1034 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Read_WarningLimit 1157
1157 ==> 10
#define CPXPARAM_Record 1162
1162 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Algorithm 1077
1077 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Simplex 1158
1158 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Display 1076
1076 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Sifting_Iterations 1078
1078 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Crash 1007
1007 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_DGradient 1009
1009 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Display 1019
1019 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_DynamicRows 1161
1161 ==> -1
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Iterations 1020
1020 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_LowerObj 1025
1025 ==> -2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Perturbation 1028
1028 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_Singularity 1037
1037 ==> 10
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Limits_UpperObj 1026
1026 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Perturbation_Constant 1015
1015 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Perturbation_Indicator 1027
1027 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_PGradient 1029
1029 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Pricing 1010
1010 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Refactor 1031
1031 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Feasibility 1016
1016 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Markowitz 1013
1013 ==> 0.01
#define CPXPARAM_Simplex_Tolerances_Optimality 1014
1014 ==> 1.000000000e-06
#define CPXPARAM_SolutionType 1147
1147 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_Threads 1067
1067 ==> 0
#define CPXPARAM_TimeLimit 1039
1039 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_DetTimeLimit 1139
1139 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Display 1113
1113 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Measure 1110
1110 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_Repeat 1111
1111 ==> 1
#define CPXPARAM_Tune_TimeLimit 1112
1112 ==> 2147483647
#define CPXPARAM_WorkDir 1064
1064 ==> .
#define CPXPARAM_WorkMem 1065
1065 ==> 2048
```

Answer (score 0):

This DOcplex code prints all default values for parameters:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

def print_parameter_defaults(m):
    for p in m.parameters:
        print(f"- parameter: {p.get_qualified_name(include_root=False)}, default= {p.default_value}")

print_parameter_defaults(Model())
```

with output (non-exhaustive)

```
- parameter: advance, default= 1
- parameter: clocktype, default= 2
- parameter: dettimelimit, default= 1e+75
- parameter: lpmethod, default= 0
- parameter: optimalitytarget, default= 0
- parameter: parallel, default= 0
- parameter: paramdisplay, default= 1
- parameter: qpmethod, default= 0
- parameter: randomseed, default= 202009243
- parameter: record, default= 0
...
```

This said, for a given version of CPLEX, all APIs should have the same parameter defaults, so I suggest checking first the versions you ar eusing.